# Form type parameter not accessible by swagger

Tags: flask, swagger, swagger-ui, flask-restful

I am using flasgger to provide a swagger spec for my flask app. For a particular endpoint I need form type parameters.

```
Update user address
---   
 parameters:
     - name: user_id
       in: path
       type: integer
       required: true
     - name: address
       in: form
       type: string
       required: true
       description: Address.
```

The method related to this endpoint is :

```
def update_address(user_id):
    approved_by = request.form.get('address')
    result = user.approve_sample(user_id, address):
    return json.dumps("OK"), 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
```

However, the address which is a form type parameter does not get updated in the database. Any suggestion why is it not registering address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `formData` in the `in` field, as specified in the [OpenAPI Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md):

```
 - name: address
   in: formData
```

Note that possible values are `query`, `header`, `path`, `formData` or `body`.

Comment: Well this did work. But I did not understand the difference between the form and formData.

Comment: @user3527975 it's just the way it is specified by the OpenAPI initiative.  They decided to call it formData, not form. 'form' is simply not a possible value for that parameter. Flasgger follows this specification for it's API definitions.